# Grey out a div using a checkbx

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to grey out / disable a div when a checkbox is selected.

Anyone can help me with an example on JSfiddle maybe?

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/albertoc/vFrAB/5/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap" style="width:500px">
    <div id="content">
        <p>This box will be disabled! <a href="#">Link</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="darkLayer" class="darkClass" style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="checkbox">
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.darkClass
{
    background-color: white;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* IE */
    opacity: 0.5; /* Safari, Opera */
    -moz-opacity:0.50; /* FireFox */
    z-index: 20;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function dimOff()
{
    document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display = "none";
}
function dimOn()
{
    document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display = "";
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? The transparent overlay seems to work fine. What do you need help with?

Comment: If the checkbox is checked, then it immediately becomes uncheckable since the other div is overlaying it. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you Mathieu. The transparent overlay works fine itself, but I cannot make it working with the checkbox.

Comment: @j08691 No, that's why the checkbox is in a separate div. Checkbox should be always available. If you select it, overlay 'disable' the content div. If you de-select it, the 'content' div becomes available.

Comment: But the issue is, since your overlay div overlays the checkbox, you then cannot click the checkbox to disable the overlay. See? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vFrAB/12/

Comment: @j08691 That's not an issue, I will resize the overlay in order to leave out the checkbox. For now, I'd like just to make it working, when you select the checkbox the overlay should activate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I combined your two functions into one and gave your checkbox a higher z-index than your overlay so that it remains clickable.

```
function dim(cb) {
    document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display = (cb.checked) ? '' : 'none';
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vFrAB/13/)**

CSS

```
#checkbox {
    position:relative;
    z-index:21;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrap" style="width:500px">
    <div id="content">
        <p>This box will be disabled! <a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="darkLayer" class="darkClass" style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="checkbox">
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" onchange="dim(this)" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `.darkLayer` into *#content*

```html
<div id="wrap" style="width:500px">
    <div id="content">  
        <div id="darkLayer" class="darkClass" style="display:none"></div>
        <p>This box will be disabled! <a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="checkbox">  
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Give *#content* styling so it becomes an *offsetParent/scrollParent*.

```css
#content {
    position:relative;
}
```

Attach listener to checkbox

```js
var i = 0;
document.getElementById("myCheckBox").addEventListener('click', function () {
   [dimOff, dimOn][i=1-i](); 
});
```

Now `.darkLayer` will only cover *#content* and not the second `<div>` holding the checkbox.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vFrAB/14/)